# Create a dropdown directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to create a custom dropdown directive using Angular, This is as far I have reached.

I am trying close the dropdown on click outside or on esc key press. Also how can I enable inside click because right now the dropdown is closing if i click any of the items inside dropdown.

```
@HostBinding('class.show') isOpen = false;

@HostListener('click') toggleDropdown() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    const elem = this._elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');
    if (this.isOpen) {
      this._renderer.addClass(elem, 'show');
    } else {
      this._renderer.removeClass(elem, 'show');
    }
}


<div class="dropdown" dropdown>
    <a
        href="#"
    >
        Dropdown link
    </a
    >
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your directive a little and added the features which you wanted. Please check and let me know if its ok.

1. on click of dropdown items its not closing the dropdown.
2. on click of outside the dropdown list its closing the list

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gu9ndu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: thank you for your response, one thing i want to ask. How can i pass a input parameter clickedInside as boolean. if i make it true dropdown will not close on clicking inside menus. If the parameter is false then menu will close on inside click

Comment: check now.. for action option click now it will close.. same way you can do.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gu9ndu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: can you check this link, it is not working as expected, what am i doing wrong here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lvx5xq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I have used ngOnChanges which you didn't use. Please follow the code fully.. otherwise it may not work..

Comment: is there any way to do it without ngOnChanges?